# I need help on android Toast view as icon on error

Tags: java, android, drawable, show, toast

My activity is a Video Player Activity and its working fine, On some Videos it must throw a message (handleHardwareAccelerationError) if the video is not supported or high quality.
It shows as Toast with message fine.
Now I would like to change this Toast message to show a picture or small icon instead, is this possible? Here is my code for handleHardwareAccelerationError, Thanks in advance.

```
private void handleHardwareAccelerationError() {
    mHardwareAccelerationError = true;
    if (mSwitchingView)
        return;

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.hardware_acceleration_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

what I have tried is this but didnt show anything.

```
private void handleHardwareAccelerationError() {
    mHardwareAccelerationError = true;
    if (mSwitchingView)
        return;
            final View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myinforbar, null);
    mError = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.errornew);
    mError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



}
```

and here is myinforbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button5_background">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/errornew"
                android:src="@drawable/everyone_icon_nearby_cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

EDITED:

The original activity is long and it can be found here rather then pasting the whole activity you can see it here [VideoPlayerActivity](https://github.com/tianshaokai/vlc-android/blob/master/vlc-android/src/org/videolan/vlc/gui/video/VideoPlayerActivity.java)
( private void handleHardwareAccelerationError)

New Update...

[image]

This is without the message (onHardwareError) applied, I want to see icon inside this bottom little box that popup when video playing (infobar) instead of Toast message.

Comment: Try [tastytoast](https://github.com/yadav-rahul/TastyToast), it looks awesome and cool with animation.

Answer (score 1):

Toast is farily limited, you cannot show icons.
Edit: Gunjav Dave says it's possible, so it's approach worth a try.

Anyway this free library: [SuperToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts)

can make what you need.

If you prefer to stick to Google's standards you can use, instead, the [Snackbars](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html), that don't allow, as far as I know, to put an icon, but can anyway be associated with an action/button, and they are *standard*.

I can't understand what you try to do with popupView, if you want to use a PopupWindow you have to use a completely different syntax. [This Balloon Popup library](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/BalloonPopup) of mine helps you to make a popup attached to a View, using a PopupWindow, you can also inflate into it a layout, or use it as an example on how to make a PopupWindow.

Edit:
You are inflating a layout inside a view, but this doesn't show the view. Instead, you should use a PopupWindow, and inflate inside it a layout.
This is an example taken from my BalloonPopup library:

```
// ....
    hostedView = ((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(layoutRes, null);
    textView = (TextView) hostedView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText(text);
// ....
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(hostedView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In other words, you should be able to do something like

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new popupWindow(mError, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

in your code to show the popup window.

These are the essential points of the code, then you can reposition the popup, and eventually keep track of it to edit and re-show it instead of always creating from scratch. Please consider, anyway, to use [BalloonPopup library](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/BalloonPopup), that does what you need, without getting crazy with animations, display times, window's permanence and positioning. You can just inflate into it your layout, for example with an icon and a text, and make it appear exactly on the center of another View, that can be your (already present) media player.

More edit:
Another very simple solution.
To get it simple, create a RelativeLayout, that hosts all your video player, and then create a simple ImageView in the center of it. Set its visibility to GONE when hidden and to VISIBLE when the error must be shown. Subsequently, you can use a timer or a touchListener to close it making it GONE again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help, the reason I am using Popupview its an Infor-Bar that shows information about the playing media like name, duration, category etc. I would like to show the toast message inside this Infor-Bar in the layout ID R.id.errornew as an icon rather then Toast.

Comment: I made some update to my comment to answer you. Please consider giving it a plus if you think it's useful, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Beppis but as I am new to android I am having difficulties to understand where to put your example in my code. The full code is a vlc android ( VideoPlayerActivity ) the info bar does shows and all working, its just the toast that shows i wanted to be icon rather then text, the vlc video player activty have a toast to show on HD or 4K video so all i need to edit is (handleHardwareAccelerationError) do I need to create new layout even if already already have them working?, possible you can post a full example that matched my layout xml or look at oroginal Vlc android here

Comment: org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity. in the section where its says   private void handleHardwareAccelerationError

Comment: I really don't know, I don't know what source code you are talking about, neither which one of the 4 solutions you would like to implement.

Answer (score 0):

XML Name or Layout Name would be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:androidclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:gravity="center_vertical" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button5_background">

<ImageView  
android:id="@+id/errornew"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Put This in Class:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); 
View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.myinforbar, null);
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());  
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);  
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Hi where should I add this code , I mean I dont see any layout ids here ? sorry total noob here please explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: R.layout.mytoast? where is this?

Comment: Create a xml named "mytoast" and use xml code mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes but i already have a layout called my infobar and I want to show the icon on the layout id called  android:id="@+id/errornew" sorry none of this in here so I got many error and also From it cannot be resolved , dear many thanks for the help but can you look at my edited xml and tell me exactly what to put here. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check. Upvote if correct

Comment: From is red? any help thanks and so sorry for this as i am noob on java

Comment: OK. You are adding Code in Fragment or activity. If Fragment then do like this "From(this.getActivity())" and for activity use in the same way

Comment: Hi thanks again I am using Activity , Please see the edited post I have added the link to the activity.

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.myinforbar, this);

Comment: can you please edit your answer so i can try, I dont know where to put this dear

Comment: Hi Gunjan possible you can set an example please.? Thanks

Comment: Hi Gunjan Dave you almost there!. With the above code its showing the whole layout (myinfobar) on  handleHardwareAccelerationError which is at least you changed the typical toast to show as layout, but what I wanted is the show an image that is inside myinfobar layout (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.errornew). I am sure you can fix this easy as the error its working but its showing the whole popupwindows. Thanks

Comment: I want the imageView that is in myinforbar layout to be visible, my inforbar layout have the imageview id called errornew

Comment: please show me the screen of how it looks and how you want ?

Comment: Ok I updated my Qestion and I hope its helpful. What you see in that pic is small inforbar at the bottom that I wanted my image to show (The English Flat onHardwareAccelaration0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  private void handleHardwareAccelerationError() {
            mHardwareAccelerationError = true;
            if (mSwitchingView)
                return;
                    final View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myinforbar, null);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView , 300, 400, true);
        pw.showAtLocation(popupView , Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
mError = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.errornew);
            mError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: I tried this dear but it almost looks the same as mine so nothing is showing     on. I have added the xml file for reference. Thanks

Comment: pw.showAtLocation(popupView , Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); In your code you are not showing popup window

Comment: yes you right pw.showAtLocation(popupView , Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); wasn't in my original code but still didnt work for me, any suggestion?

Comment: It works fine in my case do not call directly inside onCreate() method use setContentView(some layout) and then use this part of code it will work fine.

Comment: By pasting this code I didnt get any error, but it didnt show the icon on error as i wanted and also this code must be used inside Vlc VideoPlayerActivity on private void handleHardwareAccelerationError not anywehere else acording to original Vlc android so i cant change where to use just wanted to edit the original activity from showToast to show Ican, please see the full activity in vlc android github